# Adding colspan via XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-stylesheet

I am new to xslt and facing a problem while developing an XSL file that transforms XML files into a html table. Can we control closing of `<td>` somehow. For example if `size-for-desktop=8` colspan is `8`, close `td` and for next `aga-block`, if `size-for-desktop=4` control closing of `</td>` only when sum reaches `8`(size-for-desktop=4 + size-for-desktop=4) and for next `aga-block`, if `size-for-desktop=2` control closing of `</td>` only when sum reaches `8`(size-for-desktop=2 + size-for-desktop=6)

**XML file:**

```
<aga-root>
    <aga-section type="default">
        <aga-block size-for-desktop="8" >
            <aga-text>1</aga-text>
        </aga-block>
        <aga-block size-for-desktop="4" >
            <aga-text>2</aga-text>
        </aga-block>
        <aga-block size-for-desktop="4" >
            <aga-text>3</aga-text>
        </aga-block>
        <aga-block size-for-desktop="2" >
            <aga-text>4</aga-text>
        </aga-block>
        <aga-block size-for-desktop="6" >
            <aga-text>5</aga-text>
        </aga-block>
        <aga-block size-for-desktop="8" >
            <aga-text>6</aga-text>
        </aga-block>
    </aga-section>
</aga-root>
```

**XSL file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.1">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:param name="AccessKey" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tbody>
<xsl:for-each select="//aga-section">
<xsl:call-template name="ExploreAgaSection">
<xsl:with-param name="Node" select="." />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="ExploreAgaSection">
<xsl:param name="Node" />
<tr>
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" style="background-color:#fff; border-collapse:collapse; ">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@size-for-desktop = 8">
    <xsl:for-each select="aga-block[@size-for-desktop]">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="colspan"><xsl:value-of select="@size-for-desktop"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="ExploreAgaText">
        <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="aga-block[@size-for-desktop!=8]">
        <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="colspan"><xsl:value-of select="@size-for-desktop"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="ExploreAgaText">
        <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</table>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="ExploreAgaText">
<xsl:param name="Node" />
<xsl:copy-of select="$Node/aga-text/node()" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**current output:**

```
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" style="background-color:#fff; border-collapse:collapse; ">
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="4">2</td>
                 <td colspan="4">3</td>
                 <td colspan="2">4</td>
                 <td colspan="6">5</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

**expected output**

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" style="background-color:#fff; border-collapse:collapse; ">
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="8">1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="4">2</td>
                 <td colspan="4">3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">4</td>
                 <td colspan="6">5</td>
              </tr>
                 <td colspan="8">6</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

[xsl transform](http://xsltransform.net/3N7GxE6)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A few things : how do you determine what your maximum sum of colspan is per row? which XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: @Sebastien Thanks for your response. Maximum sum of colspan is set to 8 by default and "xslt-processor": "^0.11.5"

Comment: I don't think that's an XSLT engine name!

Comment: oops.I am sorry about that. do u mean environment, its nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT is immutable so recursion should be used for keeping the state.

Note the 'split' template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.1">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="AccessKey"/>

    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="from_including"  select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="to_excluding" select="2"/>
        <xsl:param name="max_size"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sum_so_far"
            select="sum(aga-block[$from_including &lt;= position() and position() &lt; $to_excluding]/@size-for-desktop)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$sum_so_far > 0">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$sum_so_far >= $max_size or count(aga-block) &lt; $to_excluding">
                    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each
                            select="aga-block[$from_including &lt;= position() and position() &lt; $to_excluding]">
                            <xsl:text>&#x0A;    </xsl:text>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@size-for-desktop"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:call-template name="ExploreAgaText"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="from_including" select="$to_excluding"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="to_excluding" select="$to_excluding + 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="max_size" select="$max_size"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="from_including" select="$from_including"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="to_excluding" select="$to_excluding + 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="max_size" select="$max_size"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta content="text/html charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//aga-section">
                            <xsl:call-template name="ExploreAgaSection">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="."/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="ExploreAgaSection">
        <xsl:param name="Node"/>
        <tr>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0"
                style="background-color:#fff; border-collapse:collapse; ">
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="max_size" select="8"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="ExploreAgaText">
        <xsl:param name="Node" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$Node/aga-text/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Working great